# ¿está mal planteada esta sentencia?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en php

```
$q = "SELECT sol.FECHA_SOLICITUD,sol.ESTADO_SOLICITUD,cli.CI_CLIENTE,cli.NOMBRE_CLIENTE,cli.APELLIDO_CLIENTE,ser.DESCRIPCION_SERVICIO,ser.COSTO_SERVICIO
         FROM solicitudes sol
         INNER JOIN clientes cli ON sol.COD_SOLICITUD = cli.COD_CLIENTE
         INNER JOIN servicios ser ON sol.COD_SERVICIO = ser.COD_SERVICIO
         WHERE sol.COD_SOLICITUD = '$id'";
```

la puse en mysql omitiendo la parte del `where` y si me devolvió varias filas pero cuando intente ejecutar la misma consulta sin quitar la parte del `where` me dice que tengo un error de sintaxis, **talvez alguien sabe por qué puede ocurrir esto?** aunque imprimiendo en pantalla la variable es del mismo tipo de dato.

Comment: Igual si agregas el mensaje de error completo será mas fácil apoyar

Comment: Intenta cambiar `FROM solicitudes sol` por `FROM solicitudes AS sol`

Comment: Si, justamente esa parte me está señalando el mysql

Comment: que dice el error?

Answer (score 2):

Sin conocer las estructuras de sus tablas es complicado determinar la causa del problema, pero parece ser un tema en la definición de las columnas.

Con las siguientes estructuras de tablas su sentencia funcionaría:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
  `servicios`,
  `clientes`,
  `solicitudes`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `servicios` (
  `COD_SERVICIO` SERIAL,
  `DESCRIPCION_SERVICIO` VARCHAR(4000),
  `COSTO_SERVICIO` DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
  `COD_CLIENTE` SERIAL,
  `CI_CLIENTE` VARCHAR(20),
  `NOMBRE_CLIENTE` VARCHAR(50),
  `APELLIDO_CLIENTE` VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `solicitudes` (
  `COD_SOLICITUD` SERIAL,
  `COD_SERVICIO` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `ESTADO_SOLICITUD` BOOL,
  `FECHA_SOLICITUD` DATETIME
);
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10f11b1dc4486a1e084e16b91a4fbb9e).

Comment: ¿Tu respuesta es cambiar la definición de las tablas?